# What are all of the monad naming conventions?

Tags: haskell, monads

It seems that Haskell has established several naming conventions around monads.

Examples:

- appending `T` to the end to obtain the name of the monad transformer (e.g. `Reader` -> `ReaderT`)
- using `runXXX` to perform a monad computation (e.g. `runST`, `runReader`)
- `liftXXX` for various values of `XXX`

Are there other naming conventions?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

- `runX m` where `m :: X a` will run the `X` monad and return the "side effect" along with the monad result, `a`.
- `evalX m` will run the computation and return the result, `a`.
- `execX m` will run the computation and return the "side effect" but not the result.
- The lifts come in various flavors that can be a bit too tricky for me to want to explain them in a SO answer.  You should probably know `lift` and `liftIO` and be aware of / eventually seek out the other variants such as `liftWith` and `liftBaseWith`.  See, for example, EZYang's posting on the topic.
- appending a `T` after the monad name implies transformer.  Appending an `M` after a function name implies it is monadic.  Appending an `_` implies the result is ignored.
- All other suffixed letters mean "use hoogle".

Comment: As a short addendum http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Control-Monad.html#g:2 describes a few of the combinator naming conventions with regards to when the M suffix as opposed to the m prefix are appropriate.