# Intuition for "run" function of monads

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, monads

I'm learning about monads in Haskell, I understood why they are useful, I understood in general what bind, join, return do.

I also looked at basic usage examples for the basic reader / writer / state / list / maybe monads.

Still, being a beginner, I still don't feel I have a grip on what the "run" function (e.g. runState, runReader, runWriter) mean in general. It does not seem to have a generic signature like the above functions, and I don't get it if it's definable / makes sense for all monads.

Comment: If you mean functions like `runState`, `runReader` etc. then no, these don't exist for all monads.

Comment: The various `run*` functions take a "chain" of functions linked together by `>>=`, and return the value produced by finally evaluating all the functions in order.

Comment: The "generic" signature can be seen as a T-algebra; taking a monadic value and "extracting" whatever value the wrapped code produces when finally evaluated. `>>=` typically doesn't do anything except build up a bigger chain of deferred code.

Comment: Often, the `run*` functions are no-ops, but merely expose the internal representation of the monad. E.g., `Reader r a` is a wrapper for `r -> a` and `runReader` converts the former into the latter. The same applies for `Writer w a`, which wraps `(w, a)`, and for `State s a` which wraps `s -> (s, a)`. After having built a (potentially long and complex) monadic computation, one uses `run*` to finally let that computation interact with the rest of the program which does not live under the same monad.

Comment: @chi You should post that as an answer

Comment: @Bergi Agreed. Cubic's answer below already covers my point above, so I lazily upvoted that instead :)

Comment: You might also like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9458700/what-are-all-of-the-monad-naming-conventions/9458784#9458784

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `run` function for most monads is actually just an artifact of how the monad is internally represented; For example, the `Reader` monad could theoretically be represented as just

```
type Reader r a = r -> a
```

`State` as

```
type State s a = s -> (s, a)
```

and so on. However, if we did that then we couldn't provide different typeclass (including `Monad`) implementations for `Reader` and `State` as they'd both just be represented by `(->)`.

-- that is, if we wrote

```
instance Functor (Reader r)
  -- ....
```

and

```
instance Functor (State s)
  -- ...
```

our compiler would complain we're trying to give two different `Functor` implementations for `(->) a`.

So instead of `type` we just more or less write the same thing with `newtype`, e.g.

```
newtype Reader r a = Reader { runReader :: r -> a }
```

or

```
newtype State s a = State { runState :: s -> (s, a)}
```

As you can see, the `run` functions don't actually *do* anything here, they just "unwrap" the newtype so we can get the underlying value.

(actual implementations may involve monad transformers and therefore look a bit more complicated, but they're essentially still doing the same thing).